# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: javascript, html

I have no idea why it keeps showing me this error. I searched a few dozen similar questions, but I probably don't have the knowledge to reproduce it in my code, or the problem is right in front of me and I simply can't see it. The HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Rodrigo Andrade de Oliveira">
    


    <style>
    
        #imgUpld {
            height: 120px;
            width: 90px;
        }

        body { 
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px;
        }

        th { 
            background:#999999; text-align:right; vertical-align:top;
        }

        input {
            width:181px;
        }

        button {
            width: 181px;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <th>Nome:</th>
        <td><input name="txtNome" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Telefone:</th>
        <td><input name="txtTel" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Endereço:</th>
        <td><input name="txtEndereco" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Função:</th>
        <td><input name="txtFuncao" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Posto:</th>
        <td><input name="txtPosto" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Foto:</th>
        <td><input name="foto" type="file" onchange="funcFoto(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><button id="btnProximo" onclick="gerarCracha()">Próximo</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        

<img id="imgUpld">
<div id="nome"></div>
<div id="telefone"></div>
<div id="endereço"></div>
<div id="função"></div>
<div id="posto"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="cracha.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the JS:

```
var outImage ='imgUpld';


function funcFoto(obj)
{
    if (FileReader)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(obj.files[0]);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        var image=new Image();
        image.src=e.target.result;
        image.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById(outImage).src=image.src;
        };
        }

    }
    else
    {
            // Not supported
    }
}

function gerarCracha(){

    
    document.getElementById('nome').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtNome').value;
    document.getElementById('telefone').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtTel').value;
    document.getElementById('endereço').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtEndereco').value;
    document.getElementById('função').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtFuncao').value;
    document.getElementById('posto').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtPosto').value;

    
}
```

The problem shows up in these lines:

```
document.getElementById('nome').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtNome').value;
document.getElementById('telefone').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtTel').value;
document.getElementById('endereço').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtEndereco').value;
document.getElementById('função').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtFuncao').value;
document.getElementById('posto').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtPosto').value;
```

If I change document.getElementById('txtNome').value; to a string, the innerHTML changes just fine. Even if I manually set values to txtNome, txtTel, txtEndereco, txtFuncao, txtPosto, it still wont work.

The image preloading works fine (not my code).

What I intend to do (if I can make this work) e apply some css to the divs and generate a work badge after.

Comment: One or more of your `getElementById` call returns `null`.

Comment: It's a simple problem: one of your `.getElementById()` calls is returning `null`, which means that an element you *think* is part of the page is actually not.

Comment: Also `.getElementById()` is for locating elements by their "id" attributes, not their "name" attributes.

Comment: I've copied / pasted your code in jsfidle, I have no error, how to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @CedricCholley Just hit the `Próximo` button -> https://jsfiddle.net/6u1nyb9z/

Comment: I looked at the code 100 times and saw "id" instead of "name" 100 times. Was right in front of me, thx everyone its working perfectly now!